# How to add given public ssh key to my server

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

So, my question is if I am given a public key how am I going to use it to allow access to a user?

Apart from the real one user that I want to add, for testing purposes I have created an another user; for example `user1`.

I have created the `user1` and I have added the key to the `root` directory `/authorized_keys` and I also changed my `sshd_config` to allow access via SSH only.

However, do I need to add something to my `user1` directories?

I’ve seen lots of tutorials but still, I can’t figure it out.

Commands I used:

```
[root]#ssh-keygen
[root]#ip-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user1@ip_address
```

Note, thet the last command doesn't copy my `user1` public key to (root directories) `authorized_keys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but likely the wrong location.

Normally, especially on Linux desktop/server distros the list of ssh public keys for a user is located in `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys`, with all the public keys listed in that.

The config file directive that defines the appropriate location for OpenSSH is `AuthorizedKeysFile` (typically in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)

Comment: So, what should I do ? Run those commands in [user1]#?

Comment: I usually just copy and paste the ssh key into the appropriateauthorized_keys file (or equivalent action) - creating the file if it does not exist.

Comment: So, copy paste the user1's public key inside [user1]# authorized_keys file?

Comment: I dont know what [user1]# means - i would copy it into ~user1/.ssh/authorized_keys  (Assuming that user1 is the user you want the user to be able to log in as)

Comment: thanks for the answer. [user1] # i mean when connected as user1. After that i should also create a sshd_config file in user1 directories?

Comment: turns out that's what I should have done ! Thanks a lot!